# Extent of Decentralization in Hyperledger

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

In Hyperledger, does the decentralization ends at the organization level?
or can it be also extended after the organization level i.e in the peers and client level?

According to what I understand -> if he/she wants then the Admin of an organization is able to control everything and take control of any Peer/ Client/ Member and can access their rights and do transactions by their name.

can we say that the Admin completely owns the organization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure you can say that an Admin completely owns the organization.  What an admin or non-admin user can do is determined by access control lists.  These determine who can do what.  When combined with endorsement policies, one can ensure that changes require decentralized agreement.

Comment: So for an organization can there be 2 Admins and all the control can be divided between.

Comment: There can be as many admins or non-admins from any number of organizations.  It's up to the owner of the MSP to add the public certificates to the correct directories.

Comment: so who do you think actually owns an organization, and what do you believe is hyperledger decentralized?

Comment: Probably the closest thing to an organization owner is whomever controls the CA.  What do you believe is centralized?  With the Raft based ordering service, each organization can bring their own ordering service nodes (OSNs) and be part of the ordering service.  They can bring their own peers, their own CAs, etc.  So it seems pretty decentralized to me.  Is it permissionless?  No, but that doesn't make it centralized.